# Cannot seem to find jQuery

Tags: 8, javascript

The jQuery module is said to be part of core in Drupal 8, but I couldn't find on the admin pages and still pages are loaded without any jQuery links.

I am using the Bootstrap theme. How do I set it up to load jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the jQuery Update module that is not necessary with Drupal 8, since [*Drupal 8 ships with the latest jQuery, and the plan is to continue increasing the shipped version (with BC available) in further minor releases*](https://www.drupal.org/node/2607768).
Drupal always used the jQuery library; the jQuery Update module is only necessary to use a version of jQuery different from the one shipped with Drupal.

As for loading jQuery together the theme assets, as explained in [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets) you need to add core/jquery to the dependencies. For example, the following content of an hypothetic fluffiness.libraries.yml file would load the jQuery library on the pages where the theme with that file is used.

```
cuddly-slider:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/cuddly-slider.css: {}
  js:
    js/cuddly-slider.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript and CSS assets in Drupal 8 are implemented as libraries. There is [an API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets) for adding those to your modules and themes. jQuery is one of them.